# how to calculate minimum distance between an ellipsoid hull and a point in R

Tags: r, distance, point, ellipse

I applied the ellipsoidhull() function in R to a set of latlong points. From there I am trying to find the minimum distance between that ellipsoid and a new latlong point. So far I have the code below but it is certainly incomplete. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
df <- cbind(A$lat, A$long)
ellipse <- ellipsoidhull(df)

point <- (28.5,-81.2)

distance <- spDistsN1(ellipse, point, longlat = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found an answer although not exact. I was missing the predict function so:

```
df <- cbind(A$lat, A$long)
ellipsePoints <- ellipsoidhull(df)
ellipse <- predict(ellipsePoints)

ellipse <- cbind(ellipse$longpts,ellipse$latpts)
point <- (longpt,latpt)

distance <- spDistsN1(ellipse, point, longlat = FALSE)

if anyone else has a more accurate way please let me know, thank you.
```